# Trouble replacing cartridge for a 2 handle bathroom faucet

Tags: plumbing, faucet, cartridge, delta

I am trying to install new cartridges for my faucet, but after removing the old ones and putting the new ones in, water will not come out from either handle after I turn it on.
[image]
On the left is the new cartridge, while on the right is the old one. I think I got the right kind, but correct me if I am wrong. They look similar except that the new one has small teeth in that opening, but the old does not.
I tried putting back the old ones in, but I still have the same issue. I figure at this point that I am doing a mistake while putting them back on.
[image]
[image]
Here's how it looks after I put it, does it look right? I am having trouble pushing it down even further if that's what I need to do so any tips concerning that would be welcomed.
Thank you so much for your help

EDIT: Here are extra pictures.
Bottom of both old and new cartridges.
[image]

How it looks with everything removed:
[image]

Comment: Could you please *look at* and post a picture showing the **bottom** of both the old and new cartridges? Also, can you edit in a pic showing the inside of the faucet where the cartridge insert? This will help. Test- to ensure no upstream issue: if the cartridges are removed, will water shoot up out of the faucet valve area when you open the supply stop-valves?

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have attached the pictures you asked for. Also, the water does shoot up out of the faucet when I have everything removed.

Comment: If you look at the side of the cartridge near the bottom, you will see the rectangular port that the water flows through to the spout. That must face the proper direction (most likely *toward* the spout, i.e. toward the inboard). It is easy to inadvertently insert the cartridge 180° the wrong direction. If inserting in the correct position causes the handles to be positioned incorrectly, then you need cartridges that are *handed*, i.e. specific one for left and right side.

Comment: I see the rectangular port and I tried to align it towards the spout, and it does make sense, as I can tell that there's a hole in that direction. However, it appears to not be the correct way to put in, as the tips of the cartridge would be facing the incorrect way and would not go on their designated spot, and when I try to put the handle on, I cannot do that because it would be hitting the wall. Therefore I am not sure what is happening, I do have both the hot and cold cartridges by the way and they appear to have the same issue.